# Parameter with leading underscore in existing store procedure

Tags: entity-framework-4

We have update store procedure that we have to use that have the parameter as `_ModifiedBy`.
EF create mapping and add p letter to the parameter name like `p_ModifiedBy`, that I can not change.
When the program call to the store procedure it fails with no `_ModifiedBy` parameter was supplied.
Changing the parameter name to start with letter fixes the problem but there is a lot of logic based on that underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the redundant "p" letter from the parameter definition in both CSDL and SSDL parts of the model (using XML Editor). Everything should work smoothly. 
Unfortunately, these changes will be discarded after any Update Wizard from database call, it is a known limitation of this wizard.

Comment: Thank you! It works! Do you know how to map existing CUD storeprocedures that have some not existing in database parameter?

Comment: As far as I understood, you need to call a method with a number of parameters greater than the one of the corresponding stored procedure?
Actually, there is no easy way to achieve this. Try something like the OnSavingChanges event, and call procedures manually for the necessary entities.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully I will not need to use existing storeprocedures and just use standard EF way.